# How to compare Realm schemas from Android and iOS realm file

Tags: android, ios, database-migration, realm

I've implemented database in realm on Android an iOS. I'm hardly sure that they are the same but if I'm replacing file from iOS and getting Realm instance using this file I get RealmMigrationNeededException. Is there any way to compare schemas in realm files from Android and iOS? If I'm doing the same action with file from another Android device it works.

Edit:

After adding empty Migration:

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {

    @Override
    public long execute(Realm realm, long version) {
        return version;
    }
}
```

I get: "Primary key not defined for field 'id' in existing Realm file. Add @PrimaryKey." Both platforms have 'id' field implemented as primary key.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't exit a tool yet that can output the entire schema unfortunately. You can use our Realm Browser for IOS, which will show you some of it, but if I remember correctly it will not show you e.g which fields are indexed: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12

The migration exception should give you some idea what is wrong though?

Comment: In exception message i get: RealmMigration must be provided. I used "Save Model Definition" and export both(iOS & Android) to Java then i compare this using FileMerger and i get 0 differences.

Comment: It might be better if you sent both files to help@realm.io together with your model files, then we can look at them to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I've added empty migration to configuration and i get message: "Primary key not defined for field 'id' in existing Realm file. Add @PrimaryKey." We have added primary key for 'id' field on both platforms.

Comment: What versions of Realm on both platforms are you using?

Comment: Android: 0.84.0, iOS: 0.96.2. What is suspicious if I use "Save Model Definition" in RealmBrowser it doesn't add @PrimaryKey annotation in the output model files.

Comment: I've removed @PrimaryKey annotation on Android and I've import realm file from iOS successfully. Is it possible that information about primary key is not stored in realm file? We have declared appropriate fields as primary key on both platforms.

Comment: The primary key information is stored in the Realm file. So that sounds really strange.

Comment: Is our declaration of primary key correct?

+ (nullable NSString *)primaryKey
{
    return NSStringFromSelector(@selector(id));
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93658/discussion-between-dawid-hyzy-and-christian-melchior).

Comment: We have discovered a critical error in how primary keys are defined: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1703 and are working to fix it.

Comment: I saw that issue is closed. When are you planning to release new version?

Comment: You can already use it in our `0.84.2-SNAPSHOT`, but we will probably release a full `0.84.2` either Friday or Monday.